# Can I check items filtered by Isotope v3 before the layout is rearranged?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope v3.0.1 to show and hide atoms under different headings using `filter`. Nothing too fancy by itself, but I want to remove the headings if there are no more items under them. Best case scenario is that I can start the animation on the header as the `{ filter: ... }` call fades the atoms out. In other words, I want the sequence to be like:

1. `.isotope({ filter: selectors });` is called, and **somehow** I procure its internal list of the atoms that match it.
2. I take this list and check if any of the headings will have no elements under them.
3. Both the filter animation and my custom heading fadeout animation kick off simultaneously.

---

As I understand it, [MetaFizzy axed the callbacks as of v2](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/609) and is going purely with their `.isotope('on', 'event', () => ...)` model instead. Annoyingly though, [all relevant events](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html) trigger on some transition complete, and I'd rather not guess what transient classes Isotope applies, for fear of breaking between versions.

Is there any way to do this cleanly, or am I stuck queueing my custom functionality behind the Isotope transitions?